# How do I Fix an Unresponsive Button Listener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am currently working on a program that pulls tables from a website and converts them into csv files.  For some reason the JButton I put in the GUI to start the process is unresponsive. This version should open up a panel.  The button appears, but clicking it does nothing. How do I get my button to activate the action listener? My code is below.

```
package importfriendly;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class UserInterface extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7729565734298298985L;
    public UserInterface() {
        JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Insert URL Here");
        lab1.setLocation(250, 0);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
        jtf.setLocation(250, 50);
        JButton initiate = new JButton("Start");
        initiate.setLocation(250, 100);
        add(lab1);
        add(jtf);
        add(initiate);
        initiate.addActionListener(null);

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ;
        }
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Loading");
        frame2.setSize(100, 200);
        frame2.setResizable(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setContentPane(new Loading_Panel());
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setLocation(400, 500);
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RazorScraper");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new UserInterface());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(400, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `initiate.addActionListener(null);` to `initiate.addActionListener(this);`

plus you have a to insert the code of you creating the frame2 inside the ActionPerformed function  like this :

```
  @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Loading");
     frame2.setSize(100, 200);
     frame2.setResizable(true);
     frame2.setVisible(true);
     frame2.setContentPane(new Loading_Panel());
     frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     frame2.setLocation(400, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. The button appears to be working now, but I'm just getting errors on my actual processing file.

Comment: @KyleGunderson: Please accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' on the top left of it.